# Codeigniter 3 issue with login goes directly to the page with no verification

Tags: php, html, codeigniter-3

I have an issue where every time I click on login it just takes me to my page it seems to not be checking to see if the username or password was entered.  I am not sure what the issue is I changed the line `if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)` to true and then I just get redirected back to the login when I enter correct password. I think it is something simple I am just missing. If anyone has an idea any direction would help in the mean time I will keep figuring it out.

Controllers

**Verifylogin.php** controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class VerifyLogin extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->model('user','',TRUE);
 }

 function index()
 {
   //This method will have the credentials validation
   $this->load->library('form_validation');

   if($this->form_validation->run() == false)
   {
     //Field validation failed.  User redirected to login page
    $this->load->view('person_view');
   }
   else
   {
     //Go to private area
     redirect('Person', 'refresh');
   }

 }


 public function check_database() {

$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
$this->load->view('login_view.php');
} else {
$data = array(
'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
'password' => $this->input->post('password')
);
$result = $this->admin_database->login($data);
if($result == TRUE){
$sess_array = array(
'username' => $this->input->post('username')
);


}
}
}
}
```

**Person.php** controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Person extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('person_model','callin_list');
    }

    public function index()
    {
     if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
     {
        $this->load->view('person_view');
    }else
   {
     //If no session, redirect to login page
     redirect('login', 'refresh');
   }
    }



    public function ajax_list()
    {
        $list = $this->callin_list->get_datatables();
        $data = array();
        $no = $_POST['start'];
        foreach ($list as $callin_list) {
            $no++;
            $row = array();
            $row[] = $callin_list->Date_Scheduled;
            $row[] = $callin_list->Employee_Name;
            $row[] = $callin_list->Employee_Number;
            $row[] = $callin_list->Time_Reported;
            $row[] = $callin_list->Reason;
            $row[] = $callin_list->Scheduled_Area;
            $row[] = $callin_list->Contact;
            $row[] = $callin_list->Comments;

            //add html for action
            $row[] = '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="javascript:void()" title="Edit" onclick="edit_person('."'".$callin_list->id."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
                  <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="javascript:void()" title="Hapus" onclick="delete_person('."'".$callin_list->id."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete</a>';

            $data[] = $row;
        }

        $output = array(
                        "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
                        "recordsTotal" => $this->callin_list->count_all(),
                        "recordsFiltered" => $this->callin_list->count_filtered(),
                        "data" => $data,
                );
        //output to json format
        echo json_encode($output);
    }

    public function ajax_edit($id)
    {
        $data = $this->callin_list->get_by_id($id);
        echo json_encode($data);
    }

    public function ajax_add()
    {
        $this->_validate();
        $data = array(
                'Date_Scheduled' => $this->input->post('Date_Scheduled'),
                'Employee_Name' => $this->input->post('Employee_Name'),
                'Employee_Number' => $this->input->post('Employee_Number'),
                'Time_Reported' => $this->input->post('Time_Reported'),
                'Reason' => $this->input->post('Reason'),
                'Scheduled_Area' => $this->input->post('Scheduled_Area'),
                'Contact' => $this->input->post('Contact'),
                'Comments' => $this->input->post('Comments'),
            );
        $insert = $this->callin_list->save($data);
        echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
    }

    public function ajax_update()
    {
        $this->_validate();
        $data = array(
                'Date_Scheduled' => $this->input->post('Date_Scheduled'),
                'Employee_Name' => $this->input->post('Employee_Name'),
                'Employee_Number' => $this->input->post('Employee_Number'),
                'Time_Reported' => $this->input->post('Time_Reported'),
                'Reason' => $this->input->post('Reason'),
                'Scheduled_Area' => $this->input->post('Scheduled_Area'),
                'Contact' => $this->input->post('Contact'),
                'Comments' => $this->input->post('Comments'),
            );
        $this->callin_list->update(array('id' => $this->input->post('id')), $data);
        echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
    }

    public function ajax_delete($id)
    {
        $this->callin_list->delete_by_id($id);
        echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
    }

//validation section were user must enter data in all fields 
    private function _validate()
    {
        $data = array();
        $data['error_string'] = array();
        $data['inputerror'] = array();
        $data['status'] = TRUE;

        if($this->input->post('Date_Scheduled') == '')
        {
            $data['inputerror'][] = 'Date_Scheduled';
            $data['error_string'][] = 'Date_Scheduled is  required';
            $data['status'] = FALSE;
        }

        if($this->input->post('Employee_Name') == '')
        {
            $data['inputerror'][] = 'Employee_Name';
            $data['error_string'][] = 'Employee_Name is required';
            $data['status'] = FALSE;
        }

        if($this->input->post('Employee_Number') == '')
        {
            $data['inputerror'][] = 'Employee_Number';
            $data['error_string'][] = 'Employee_Number is required';
            $data['status'] = FALSE;
        }

        if($this->input->post('Time_Reported') == '')
        {
            $data['inputerror'][] = 'Time_Reported';
            $data['error_string'][] = 'Time_Reported is required';
            $data['status'] = FALSE;
        }

        if($this->input->post('Reason') == '')
        {
            $data['inputerror'][] = 'Reason';
            $data['error_string'][] = 'Reason is required';
            $data['status'] = FALSE;
        }
        if($this->input->post('Scheduled_Area') == '')
        {
            $data['inputerror'][] = 'Scheduled_Area';
            $data['error_string'][] = 'Scheduled_Area is required';
            $data['status'] = FALSE;
        }
        if($this->input->post('Contact') == '')
        {
            $data['inputerror'][] = 'Contact';
            $data['error_string'][] = 'contact is required';
            $data['status'] = FALSE;
        }
        if($this->input->post('Comments') == '')
        {
            $data['inputerror'][] = 'Comments';
            $data['error_string'][] = 'Comments is required';
            $data['status'] = FALSE;
        }

        if($data['status'] === FALSE)
        {
            echo json_encode($data);
            exit();
        }
    }

}
```

**login_model.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/* Author: Jorge Torres
 * Description: Login model class
 */
class Login_model extends CI_Model{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function validate(){
        // grab user input
        $username = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('username'));
        $password = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('password'));

        // Prep the query
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);

        // Run the query
        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        // Let's check if there are any results
        if($query->num_rows() == 1)
        {
            // If there is a user, then create session data
            $row = $query->row();
            $data = array(
                    'userid' => $row->userid,
                    'fname' => $row->fname,
                    'lname' => $row->lname,
                    'username' => $row->username,
                    'validated' => true
                    );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            return true;
        }
        // If the previous process did not validate
        // then return false.
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

**login_view.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
   <title>Login Form</title>

   <style type="text/css">
.content{
  margin-left: 400px;
  margin-top: 300px;
}
.btn{
width:242px;
height: 50px;
}
#label{
font-size: 24px;
font-weight: normal;
}

   </style>
   <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')?>" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="container"> 
 <div class="content">
   <h1>DC399 Callin Login Page</h1>
   <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
   <?php echo form_open('verifylogin'); ?>
     <label  id="label"for="username">Username:</label><br>
     <input type="text" size="20" id="username"style="width: 239px; height: 40px; margin-right: 20px;"name="username"/>
     <br/>
     <label id="label" for="password">Password:</label><br>
     <input type="password" size="20" id="passowrd" style="width: 239px; height: 40px; margin-right: 20px;"name="password"/>
     <br/><br>
     <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Login"/>
   </form>
   </div>
   </div>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js')?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')?>"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$this->form_validation->run() === FALSE` instead, with 3 `=` signs.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the data to verifylogin/index and any moment are loading the rules to check and validate neither are checking from the database. That's the problem.

Comment: so I need to use checkdatabase instead like verifylogin/checkdatabase

Comment: Yes, also you should change your logic to

if (statement) {
    // do Something when is true
} else {
   // do Something else when is false
}